# master slave postgresql with logging and monitoring for a django application

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-administration, django-orm

I have a django application running. 
The database backend that i use for it is PostGreSql.
Everything is working fine for me.

Now I want to create a master slave replication for my database, such that:

1. Whatever change happens on master, is replicated on slave.
2. If the master shuts down, the slave takes charge, and an error notification is sent.
3. Backup is created automatically of the database.
4. Logging is taken care of.
5. Monitoring is taken care of.

I went through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/ the entire article. 
But I don't have much idea, how to implement the all 5 steps above. As you would have understood, I don't have much experience, hence please suggest pointers around, how to proceed. Thanks.

Have I missed, anything which should be kept in mind for database purpose??

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a dual-node HA setup for PostgreSQL, using synchronous streaming replication and failover.

Check out http://repmgr.org/ for one tool that'll help with this, particularly when coupled with a PgBouncer front-end. You may also want to read about "heartbeat", "high availability", "fencing" and "STONITH".

You need to cope with the master continuing to run but failing, not just it shutting down. Consider what happens if the master runs out of disk space; all write queries will return errors, but it won't shut down or crash.

This is really an issue of database administration / server management.